# Make bit.ly use my own URL shortening service for pages on my site

Tags: url-shortening, bit.ly

I see that bit.ly have integrated with other URL shortening services to allow for custom domains in the short URL version.

E.g. When I shorten a URL from an article on TheNextWeb.com it gets shortened to tnw.co as the below illustrates:

> http://thenextweb.com/uk/2011/03/15/british-lawyer-becomes-first-to-serve-court-summons-via-facebook/

gets shortened to:

> http://tnw.co/i9pXoV

Even if I do this through bit.ly it will return the above shortened URL.

How can I get bit.ly to use my own URL shortening service for pages on my site?

Answer (score 4):

This as called End-to-End (e2e) Domain configuration and is available to bit.ly Enterprise users only which costs $995 per month.
[image: bit.ly product information]

- [Link to bit.ly Product features - shown above](http://bit.ly/pro/products)
- [Link to bit.ly Pro & Enterprise Help](http://bit.ly/pro/help)